# Need to remove extra argument at function call

Tags: c

This is my `typedef struct`

```
//command look up table structure
typedef struct
{
    int commandCode;
    int  (*process_command) (...);
}cmdTableStruct;
```

Using `int  (*process_command) (...);` i need to call appropriate function which i have assign to that if command code match.

ex.

```
static cmdTableStruct cmdTable[]=
{
 { 1123,testFunc},
 // more command in same manner
};
```

here it will call `testFunc` function if command code `1123` and argument of this function only one. Same it will call different functions but the argument type is different and argument is one.

Now using `int  (*process_command) (...);` in `stuct` definition it give me error like

```
Error:  #xx: expected a type specifier
```

I can resolve this error by adding one known type argument

like

```
int  (*process_command) (int x,...);
```

But i don't want additional argument, i just want it will take one argument and call function with appropriate data type of argument.

is any suggestions?

Comment: The ellipsis (`...`) means *zero of more* arguments. A function taking variable number of arguments must *always* have at least one real argument. That's how the variable-argument system works in C. For a great example, look at e.g. [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), it's declared as `int printf(const char *format, ...)`, and you still don't have to provide more than the initial string.

Comment: Varargs need at least one named parameter to work, so I guess that's it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, but all my functions expect only one argument and which is have different type.

Comment: If they expect the first argument to be of a different type, then you are out of luck. You might want to think about a different design, like having all functions receive the `commandCode` as the first argument.

Comment: @Jayesh then you have a design problem. Varargs won't work without a known starting point for the eventual `va_start` to base itself upon.

Comment: what about having the function argument as void *? pass inputs as pointers, typecast and copy to local variables within the functions and use them...

Comment: @WhozCraig might be it's design problem..i need to pass `commandCode` as first argument but `commandCode` no longer in use.

Comment: If you *need* to pass `commandCode` as first argument anyway, then you don't have any problem because the first argument will *always* be an `int`. You already have the solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For solution i need to pass command code as argument but really i don't need it.

Comment: @A.M.D That is one  solution i think..why not post as answer?

Comment: This would be *much* simpler if your callbacks could be of the form `void cb(va_list args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, u can consider this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int commandCode;
    int  (*process_command) (void *ptr);
}cmdTableStruct;
```

Make the argument to process_command to `void *`. Pass address of variable of whatever types you need for any specific case. Within each function, typecast to expected, copy to local variables of expected types and use.

Comment: Thanks..also it will possible using `void cb(va_list args)` as per @WhozCraig mention in comment.

Comment: In your case, u are always expecting a single argument. so why consider va_list? i don't see any reason to use va_list as your argument number is constant.